# Is there any drawback to just renaming jpeg files to jpg?

Tags: images, jpeg

A client sent me many jpeg files that I'd like to rename to jpg. Is this just a matter of renaming them, or should I open them with an image editing program and then saving them as jpg?

Comment: You can rename `*.jpeg` files to `*.jpg`. How they are handled (in particular thru their MIME type) depends upon the applications processing them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JPEG stands for Joint Photographic Experts Group. JPG (pronounced jay-peg) is the most commonly used file extension used to identify files created with this lossy format, and is the same as .jpeg. JPEG is a bitmap compression format for picture and image files with compression ratios ranging from 10:1 to 20:1. Older DOS-based computers were designed to handle a maximum "3-character file extension" which is why JPG was attributed to compressed image files. Newer Operating systems such as Windows XP and Vista allow for longer file extensions as evidenced by ".html". Accordingly, the JPG file extension was upgraded to the JPEG file extension which is the true acronym for Joint Photographic Experts Group. 
Just as a side note, XP and Vista will also support the older JPG file extension.

[Reference](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Is_there_any_difference_between_'.jpg'_and_'.jpeg')

Answer (score 20):

Extensions have no effect on the file itself.

The difference might be having different applications associated with them, in which case renaming the file might cause it to be opened by a different application by default.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you look at the description of the tags you used, you might have your answer:

"JPG is a filename extension for the JPEG image file format. JPEG is a commonly used method of lossy compression for digital photography (image)."

There should be no problem in changing the extensions.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of the file itself there is really no consequence to renaming a `JPEG` as `.jpg` or `.jpeg` or any version of it .

But there may be some association effects if you are using Windows because a `.jpeg` may be associated with one program and `.jpg` may be associated with another .

On Unix-like Operating systems like Mac or Linux , file extensions have not meaning to the OS itself and association is made based on file type and not based on file extension, So there is really no effect .

In the case of web-browsers also there is no effect to naming a `JPEG` file with any extension,How that file is handled is based on the MIME type (`CONTENT-TYPE` HTTP header) .